# Linking two separate cmake projects where one is dependant on the other

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I have two separate projects, A and B. Both have large folder structures, lots of dependencies and both have their own CMakelists.txt structures as well. Neither depend on each other.
I am adding new functionality to project A that depends on a header from project B, along with the network of files in Project B that header depends on.
I  am at a loss for the correct way to link these with cmake. I added to header as an include where necessary in my code, but am not sure the correct way to link it. Do I use target_include_directories and add the binaries from project B, or the source code, or both? Project A won't be building B as it is already set up, with the binaries and source in separate subdirectories. I just need A to be able to call the functionality from B.
I am not very familiar with cmake yet, so any pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project B should export its targets.

That way, in project A, you could do something like this:

```
find_package(B REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC B::B)
```

And when invoking CMake, add B's build directory in the prefix path:

```
# in A/build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/B/build
```

But in order for that to work, you must change your B CMake files to export your targets (as it should):

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)

add_library(B INTERFACE)
add_library(B::B ALIAS B)

target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC dependency-of-B)
target_compile_features(B INTERFACE cxx_std_17) # or any language version

# Set B include directory. Will add include directory for both B and A
target_include_directories(B PUBLIC
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/your-include-dir>
)

file(COPY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/B-config.cmake" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
install(TARGETS B EXPORT B-targets)
# install package
install(EXPORT B-targets
    FILE B-targets.cmake
    NAMESPACE B::
    DESTINATION share/cmake/B
)
# export build tree
export(
    EXPORT B-targets
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/B-targets.cmake"
    NAMESPACE B::
)
```

With `B-config.cmake`:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

# All find_package we used in CMakeLists.txt should also be there
find_dependency(dependency1 REQUIRED)
find_dependency(dependency2 REQUIRED)

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/B-targets.cmake")
```

If you have many target in B, you should `install(TARGETS other-target EXPORT B-targets)`

I strongly recommend looking at example of libraries that export their targets so you can base your work on it. For example, the `glm` library export its targets and always worked well. I also added [target exportation in `msdfgen` project](https://github.com/Chlumsky/msdfgen/pull/104/files).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use headers and not object files then just `target_include_directories` is all you need. Dependency tracking will be done by cmake and ninja/make automatically.

Alternatively, if you need to include both headers and objects from B, you'd really want to factor out these bits into small stand-alone static libraries within B, and then link with those libraries from A - this will add include file paths and everything else needed. cmake is quite good at it.